# Replace dictionary keys with values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have made a dictionary from a text file and want to use it to replace the keys that appear in a separate file with their values.

For example, my dictionary looks something like...

```
names = {1:"Bob", 2:"John", 3:"Tom"}
```

And the other file looks something like...

```
1 black cat  
2 gray elephant  
3 brown dog
```

I want it to end up being...

```
Bob black cat  
John gray elephant  
Tom brown dog
```

So far I have only written code to make the dictionary

```
names = {}  
for line in open("text.txt", 'r'):  
    item = line.split()  
    key, value = item[0], item[2]  
    names[key] = value
```

I want to open a second file and use the names dictionary to replace the keys that appear there with their values. I have seen that you can use `replace(key, dict[key])` but am not sure how.

Comment: have you tried the json module, it's much cleaner.  example:
import json
json.load(file_object) , it will convert to a python dictionary, then you can use a recursion to do the replace

Comment: The poster made no indication that the format of her data was in json.  Judging by the way she's splitting up the data, it isn't.

Answer (score 7):

Try the following code:

`new_dict = {value:key for (key,value) in old_dict.items()}`

Answer (score 5):

If you're using dictionaries, I'd load them up into two separate dictionaries and then merge them.

If you've loaded the names into `names`, and animals into `animals`, you could merge them like so:

##### Python 3

```
merged = {}
for key, name in names.items():
    merged[name] = animals[key]
```

##### Python 2

```
merged = {}
for key, name in names.iteritems():
    merged[name] = animals[key]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the dictionary values and use `replace`:

```
for key in names:
    text = text.replace(key, names[key])
```

(Being `text`your file's content.)

Comment: I thought I could just directly use it like this, but it throws back an attribute error that 'file' object has no attribute 'replace'. Same thing if I use f.splitlines() only its 'list' has no attribute 'replace'.

Comment: That's because `text` must be a string. Use `text = f.read()` before the code above!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
my_dict = {1:"Bob", 2:"John", 3:"Tom"}

with open("test.txt", "r") as f_in, open("new.txt", "w") as f_out:
    for line in f_in:
        s_line = line.split()
        new_line = [my_dict[int(s_line[0])]]
        new_line.extend(s_line[1:])
        f_out.write(" ".join(new_line) + "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mydict = {1:"Bob", 2:"John", 3:"Tom"} # this is already a dicionary so do nothing
mydict2 = {}
myfile = """1 black cat
2 gray elephant
3 brown dog
"""


# you should use with open(file, 'r') as data:  --> fyi 

# convert the file to a dictionary format
for line in myfile.split('\n'):
  chunks = line.split(' ')
  if chunks != ['']: # i needed this because of the some white space in my example
    key, value = chunks[0], chunks[1] + ' ' + chunks[2]
    mydict2[key] = value

# remember dictionaries are not sorted, so there is no guarantee things will
# match as you expect, however there is plenty of documentation
# that you can follow to sort the dictionary prior to what i'm doing below
# i'm assuming that there are always the same number of items in both dictionaries
new_dict = {}
new_values = mydict2.values() # create a list of all the values
# iterate over the dictionary item
index = 0
for k, v in mydict.items():
 new_dict[v] = new_values[index] # append the value of the first dictionary with the value from the list
 index += 1

print new_dict
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly write out to a new file with a redirect into `names`.
You also need to slice the rest of the line (`item[2]` only get the 3rd element) and join them back together:

```
names = {1:"Bob", 2:"John", 3:"Tom"}
with open("text.txt", 'r') as r, open('out.txt', 'w') as w:
    for line in fp:
        item = line.split()  
        key, value = item[0], item[1:]    # Python 2
        # key, *value = item              # Python 3
        w.write("{} {}".format(names[int(key)], ' '.join(value)))

$ cat out.txt
Bob black cat
John gray elephant
Tom brown dog
```